# Setting full rectangle background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

Help me please! how can i upload a full rectangle background image ? Where is my mistake or what a have to add? Here is my image. Please help. Hello everyone! Help me please! how can i upload a full rectangle background image ? Where is my mistake or what a have to add? Here is my image. Please help.

[image]

```css
body {
 font: 1.5em Arial;
}
.container1 {

 background-image: url(prague3.jpeg);
 margin:
 width:
 background-size:
}
.top {
 opacity: 0.8;
 font-size:65px;
 font-family: Courier new;
 text-align: center;
 background: #EBA23C;
 width: 100%;
}
ul {
 float: left;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul li {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #F05050;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #C6AEF0;
}
ul li:hover ul {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
ul li ul li{
 opacity: 0.9;
 display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
 display:block;
}

.container2 {
 background-color: #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: Courier New;
 opacity: 0.7;
 text-align: center;
 border: dashed;
}
.container3 {
background-color: #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: Courier New;
 opacity: 0.7;
 text-align: center;
 border: dashed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="container1">
<div class="top">Study in Czech Republic</div>
<ul>
<li><a>Home</a></li>
<li><a>News</a></li>
<li><a>Czech Republic</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>Facts and figures</a></li>
<li><a>Area</a></li>
<li><a>Climate</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
<li><a>Study</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>How to apply</a></li>
<li><a>Programmes</a></li>
<li><a>Scholarships</a></li>
<li><a>Tuition fees</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
<li><a>Living</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>Arrival</a></li>
<li><a>Living costs</a></li>
<li><a>Work</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
<div class="container2">
EXPERIENCE STUDYING IN THE HEART OF EUROPE
</div><br><br><br<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="container3">gdfgdfgdfg</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Looks good to me? What do you mean with: *full rectangle background image* - where should it be and how large? Maybe you're looking for `background-size: contain;`or `background-size: cover;`. More on this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: Look at this site's background image (it is an example) https://www.bachelorsportal.com/countries/7/czech-republic.html.

Comment: And that's what you want for `.container2`?

Comment: Container1 not container2

Comment: I just tried background-size: contain; it worked! Thank you so much)

Comment: For anybody who is curious: that beautiful city landscape is from the  Charles Bridge in Prague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the correct url to the container you want the background image to cover than give the desired height and width to the container.

```css
body {
 font: 1.5em Arial;
        margin: 0;
}

.container1 {

        background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvFK.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 50vh;
 width: 100%;
}
.top {
 opacity: 0.8;
 font-size:65px;
 font-family: Courier new;
 text-align: center;
 background: #EBA23C;
 width: 100%;
}
ul {
 float: left;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul li {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #F05050;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #C6AEF0;
}
ul li:hover ul {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
ul li ul li{
 opacity: 0.9;
 display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
 display:block;
}

.container2 {
 background-color: #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: Courier New;
 opacity: 0.7;
 text-align: center;
 border: dashed;
}
.container3 {
background-color: #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: Courier New;
 opacity: 0.7;
 text-align: center;
 border: dashed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="container1">
<div class="top">Study in Czech Republic</div>
<ul>
<li><a>Home</a></li>
<li><a>News</a></li>
<li><a>Czech Republic</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>Facts and figures</a></li>
<li><a>Area</a></li>
<li><a>Climate</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
<li><a>Study</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>How to apply</a></li>
<li><a>Programmes</a></li>
<li><a>Scholarships</a></li>
<li><a>Tuition fees</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
<li><a>Living</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>Arrival</a></li>
<li><a>Living costs</a></li>
<li><a>Work</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
<div class="container2">
EXPERIENCE STUDYING IN THE HEART OF EUROPE
</div><br><br><br<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="container3">gdfgdfgdfg</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: anytime, please accept this answer as correct if solution is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Add the url to background-image property to body in css and set background-size to cover and position center to make it fit in what it can.

```css
body {
 font: 1.5em Arial;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvFK.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.container1 {

 background-image: url(prague3.jpeg);
 margin:
 width:
 background-size:
}
.top {
 opacity: 0.8;
 font-size:65px;
 font-family: Courier new;
 text-align: center;
 background: #EBA23C;
 width: 100%;
}
ul {
 float: left;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul li {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #F05050;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #C6AEF0;
}
ul li:hover ul {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
ul li ul li{
 opacity: 0.9;
 display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
 display:block;
}

.container2 {
 background-color: #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: Courier New;
 opacity: 0.7;
 text-align: center;
 border: dashed;
}
.container3 {
background-color: #ccc;
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: Courier New;
 opacity: 0.7;
 text-align: center;
 border: dashed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="container1">
<div class="top">Study in Czech Republic</div>
<ul>
<li><a>Home</a></li>
<li><a>News</a></li>
<li><a>Czech Republic</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>Facts and figures</a></li>
<li><a>Area</a></li>
<li><a>Climate</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
<li><a>Study</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>How to apply</a></li>
<li><a>Programmes</a></li>
<li><a>Scholarships</a></li>
<li><a>Tuition fees</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
<li><a>Living</a>
       <ul>
<li><a>Arrival</a></li>
<li><a>Living costs</a></li>
<li><a>Work</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
<div class="container2">
EXPERIENCE STUDYING IN THE HEART OF EUROPE
</div><br><br><br<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="container3">gdfgdfgdfg</div>


</html>
```

Comment: https://www.bachelorsportal.com/countries/7/czech-republic.html look at this site's background image. want to do like this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but look your css at this part :

```css
.container1 {
 background-image: url(prague3.jpeg);
 margin:
 width:
 background-size:
}
```

You have to link your image correctly and close every style with a ; even if they are empty. Like my exemple :

```css
.container1 {
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvFK.jpg');
 margin:;
 width:;
 background-size:;
}
```

If you keep them empty, you can delete them too. Did I answer your question ?

Comment: I uploaded a my background image. Look at this